# How to pass data from context menu to alert dialog in Android?

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-alertdialog, listactivity

The method below happens when an item in a `ListActivity` is long pressed. The idea is to delete that item from the database and for that I need to call `mNotesAdapter.deleteNote(ID)`. Which works fine if I don't use an `AlertDialog`; but I should use one for delete confirmations. But I don't know how to pass the menu info, or the id itself to the `onClick` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.contextmenu_item_remove:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // VARIABLE menuInfo IS NOT ACCESSIBLE HERE, NOW WHAT?
                    mNotesAdapter.deleteNote(menuInfo.id);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();

            return true;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Maybe in times like this it's best to have an actual class that implements `OnClickListener()` so you can have a custom constructor to pass the item in to.  Also, shouldn't it be accessible if you make `menuInfo` a final reference?

Comment: It does become accessible and I just tested it in the emulator and works fine. I just don't get it lol... Since it's final, how come every time an option in the context menu is selected, a new `menuInfo` with new data is created? Is it because it's declared in the local scope of a method and will be destroyed in the end? Do a proper answer below so I can mark it as accepted please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the reference if you mark it as `final`.

To answer the other question in your comment, `final` doesn't mean the contents of the object can't be changed.  It just means that the reference can't move to another object.

When you enter that method, you're immediately creating a new reference to a new `AdapterContextMenuInfo` in the first line.  Then you're creating a new `OnClickListener` that will **only** act on that one object that `menuInfo` is creating.